JGraphT Memory leakage when check cycles
In our Spring Boot app, we're utilizing JGraphT to construct flows, and we check for flow cycles using the findSimpleCycles method, as shown in the code below:
 private static List<List<String>> getOpenLoops(Graph<String, DefaultEdge> mergedGraph) {
        List<List<String>> openLoops = new ArrayList<>();
        JohnsonSimpleCycles<String, DefaultEdge> cycleFinder = new JohnsonSimpleCycles<>(mergedGraph);
        List<List<String>> foundedCycles = cycleFinder.findSimpleCycles();
        
        for (List<String> cycle : foundedCycles) {
            if (isOpenLoop(cycle)) {
                openLoops.add(cycle);
            }
        }
        return openLoops;
    }

JGrapht dependency
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
    <artifactId>jgrapht-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>


We used this with hundreds of flows, and it worked without any issues, even with big flows. But lately, we faced an issue with a specific flow that led to a memory leak when we checked for cycles.
So, the code got stuck when cycleFinder.findSimpleCycles() was triggered.
The dot file for the flow can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OKxbxJhXoybMAxcSz4ovf3sdbfn2rkAY/view?usp=sharing
The text file for vertices/edges array can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DR_4nmAL1PwIQHUtX1Xor7VGvTQ_P6zP/view?usp=sharing
I tried to check the heap dump but couldn't find anything helpful. (I'm not experienced with memory leakage tracing, so I'm open to suggestions for courses)

This is certainly a bug in cycleFinder.findSimpleCycles(). After reducing your failing example to a minimal one, you should file a bug report with them. Also take a shot at debugging it yourself. For that I recommend adding logging inside of that method. Tracing the logs and code with it, try to build a mental model of exactly what the loop is. From there, well, debugging is always a bit of a creative process.

Thanks @btilly , I’ve added the details of the issue's root cause in this comment.
